# How to share local network over tinc?

Tags: linux, networking, routing, vpn, iproute

I have to device, eth0 192.168.8.178/22, tun0 10.0.0.2/24

I hope from 10.0.0.1 (another host) can access 192.168.8.178/22.

```
$ ip -4 addr show eth0
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,PROMISC,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    inet 192.168.8.178/22 scope global eth0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

$ ip -4 addr show tun0
33: tun0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 500
    inet 10.0.0.2/24 scope global tun0
    valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I thought add a rule from tun0 and route 192.168.8.0/22 to eth0 gw 192.168.8.1 can achive this, but it's not works.

```
$ ip ro
default via 192.168.8.1 dev eth0
10.0.0.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.2
172.17.0.0/16 dev docker0 proto kernel scope link src 172.17.0.1 linkdown
192.168.8.0/22 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.178

$ ip ru show tab tm
32765:  from 10.0.0.0/22 iif tun0 lookup tm

$ ip ro show tab tm
192.168.8.0/22 via 192.168.8.1 dev eth0
```

I can capture icmp from tun0

```
$ tcpdump -nni tun0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
17:54:44.773931 IP 10.0.0.1 > 192.168.8.110: ICMP echo request, id 14222, seq 416, length 64
17:54:45.783634 IP 10.0.0.1 > 192.168.8.110: ICMP echo request, id 14222, seq 417, length 64
```

but nothing in eth0

```
$ tcpdump -nni eth0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
```

How can I achive this ?

tun0 is for tinc, I want to expose 192.168.8.0/22 throght this node, 192.168.8.178 is accessable from other node.

```
$ tcpdump -nni tun0 icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
17:57:12.453450 IP 10.0.0.1 > 192.168.8.178: ICMP echo request, id 14223, seq 5, length 64
17:57:12.453491 IP 192.168.8.178 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 14223, seq 5, length 64
17:57:13.454498 IP 10.0.0.1 > 192.168.8.178: ICMP echo request, id 14223, seq 6, length 64
17:57:13.454537 IP 192.168.8.178 > 10.0.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 14223, seq 6, length 64
```

**EDIT**

The real question should be "How to share local network over tinc".

I thought with ip_forward enabled, this should just works. but it's not.

The another setup is

A:

```
ip link set $INTERFACE up
ip addr add 192.168.100.1/16 dev $INTERFACE

Subnet=192.168.100.1/32
```

B:

```
ip link set $INTERFACE up
ip addr add 192.168.1.105/16 dev $INTERFACE

Subnet = 192.168.1.0/24
```

From A node , I can ping 192.168.1.105, but can not ping 192.168.1.120, which is alive in the subnet. tun0 got the ping, but eth0 do not get the ping.

Comment: That isn't how routing works.  Routes tell the system where to send packets when they are destined for an unknown network ( you are not connected to ).  When you are connected to a network, there is no need for a route: the packets for that network will just go there.  Unless you have an iptables firewall rule to stop it anyhow.

Comment: It is the *other* network on the other side of the tunnel that needs a route telling it to send packets for your network to the tunnel address.

Comment: @psusi Did you mean the remote side route ? Remote ping request can make it to client, I think the route is correct, but in client, the ping can only make to tun0, not eth0.

Comment: Make sure /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward has a 1 in it.